# New Relic Pro API code instrumentation (python)

Tags: python, newrelic

I want to instrument my Python code (to be able to know how much time each line of code took)

Like for:

```
def func()
    a = some_other_func()
    for i in items:
        calculate(i)

    execute_sql_query(my_query)
    ..
    ..
```

I want to know the average time for each line of code. I don't understand from the documentation if I should use the `@newrelic.agent.wsgi_application()` decorator.

How can I measure it using New Relic?